# Different Datacontext for Command and CommandParameter

Tags: wpf, binding, command, contentcontrol, commandparameter

Is it possible to have a different `Datacontext` for a WPF `Command` and a `CommandParameter`?

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewmodels:ListViewGridBaseViewModel x:Key="vm" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="currentContent" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=ListGrid}" >
        <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Save}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=currentContent}"
                          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vm}"
                          Header="Save">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Save}"
                               Height="16"
                               Width="16"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Revert}" 
                          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vm}"
                          Header="Revert">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Revert}"
                               Height="16"
                               Width="16"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I want the `Binding` for ListGrid bubbled up to another Viewmodel and the `Command` to a local ViewModel. But the `CommandParameter` should be the `ContentControl`. 
LOG is saying:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with 
reference 'ElementName=currentContent'. BindingExpression:(no path); 
DataItem=null; target element is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); 
target property is 'CommandParameter' (type 'Object')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ContextMenu` breaks the `DataContext` inheritance chain, that's why `ElementName=currentContent` cannot be found.

Look here for [artificial inheritance context](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ArtificialInheritanceCxt.aspx) and use the class `DataContextSpy`

then do the following:

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewmodels:ListViewGridBaseViewModel x:Key="vm" />
    <local:DataContextSpy DataContext="{Binding ElementName=currentContent}" x:Key="Spy">
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ContentControl x:Name="currentContent" 
                    Content="{Binding Path=ListGrid}" >
        <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu >
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Save}" 
                          CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext,Source={StaticResource Spy}}"
                          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vm}"
                          Header="Save">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Save}"
                               Height="16"
                               Width="16"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=Revert}" 
                          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=vm}"
                          Header="Revert">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=Revert}"
                               Height="16"
                               Width="16"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ContextMenu` has a separate `VisualTree` and is not part of UserControl's `VisualTree` and that's why `Elementname` binding's won't work. A simple workaround to use `ElementName` bindings is to add this in your UserControl's code-behind

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(currentContent, NameScope.GetNameScope(this));
```

Or you can use [Enable ElementName Bindings with ElementSpy](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/enable-elementname-bindings-with-elementspy/)

Comment: Wow thanks for the explanation...
What whould now be the "best practice" solution?

Comment: It depends on you, what you find easier? all have their benefits and solves the problem. I would prefer to just add a single line of code though.

Comment: I directly implemented the Spy solution. It was just one new class in my Infrastructure Project and one new namespace in the xaml, but thats not the reason I ask.
Im wondering which solution might be better in terms of performance etc.

Comment: you will barely notice any difference in performance in all three solutions provided (DataContextSpy, ElementSpy or SetNameScope). The reason I'm always suggesting DataContextSpy is, that it is more powerful and I usually use it throughout a project on many instances.

Comment: I agree with markus, using DataContextSpy/ElementSpy makes sense if you use them in multiple places in your application; but I would go for SetnameScope for first time and later change it if required.

Comment: Not sure about performnace as that will require some effort to be sure; but I think difference shouldn't be too much to be worried about.